# Convert and check array datatype

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, type-conversion

For a python course I would like your help for an assignment.

Define a function check_conversion which takes as imput two parameters: an array and a data type. The function should return a boolean value that indicate if all elements in the initial array can be losslessly converted to the specificed data type.

Right now I have got this code, but it returns True on every input. We can only use numpy library so that is a constraint.
I am probably overthinking this and there will be a much easier solution.

```
import numpy
def check_conversion(x, d_type):


x = numpy.array([x], dtype= d_type)
dtype = ""

x_float32 = x.astype('float32')
x_float64 = x.astype('float64')
x_int = x.astype('int')
x_un_int64 = x.astype('uint64')

print(x, x.dtype)
print(x_int, x_int.astype)
print(x_float32, x_float32.dtype)


if numpy.all(x) == numpy.all(x_float32):
    return True


elif numpy.all(x) == numpy.all(x_float64):
    return True


elif numpy.all(x) == numpy.all(x_int):
    return True


elif numpy.all(x) == numpy.all(x_un_int64):
    return True

else:
    return False

a = numpy.array([3., 3.2, 1])
data_type_a = "int"
print(check_conversion(a, data_type_a))
b = numpy.array([3., 3.2, -1])
data_type_b = "float32"
print(check_conversion(b, data_type_b))
c = numpy.array([3., 3.2, -1])
data_type_c = "float64"
print(check_conversion(c, data_type_c))
d = numpy.array([3, 2, -1])
data_type_d = "uint64"
print(check_conversion(d, data_type_d))
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you fix the indentation please?

Comment: Hi, I guess you misunderstand how `np.all` is working. It gives `True` if all elements of an array are `True` and `False` otherwise. Here `0` and `0.0` are considered `False` and all other numbers are considered `True`. Your comparisons only check if both arrays contain zeros or not. You need to change your conditions to `numpy.all(x==x_float32)`. Also you only want to check the datatype that is given in in the function call. Atm you only check for float32 and if that is working give `True` end continue checking elseway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this suits you ?

```
import numpy

def check_conversion(x, d_type):
    xb = numpy.array(x, dtype= d_type)
    print x, xb
    if numpy.array_equal(x, xb):
        return d_type, True
    return d_type, False

a = numpy.array([3., 3.2, 1])
data_type_a = "int"
print(check_conversion(a, data_type_a))
b = numpy.array([3., 3.2, -1])
data_type_b = "float32"
print(check_conversion(b, data_type_b))
c = numpy.array([3., 3.2, -1])
data_type_c = "float64"
print(check_conversion(c, data_type_c))
d = numpy.array([3, 2, -1])
data_type_d = "uint64"
print(check_conversion(d, data_type_d))
```

Output

```
[ 3.   3.2  1. ] [3 3 1]
('int', False)
[ 3.   3.2 -1. ] [ 3.          3.20000005 -1.        ]
('float32', False)
[ 3.   3.2 -1. ] [ 3.   3.2 -1. ]
('float64', True)
[ 3  2 -1] [                   3                    2 18446744073709551615]
('uint64', False)
```

I'm creating a new `xb` array than i am comparing to previous `x` with `numpy.array_equal function`.

Comment: @Naugeux Thanks! Stack overflow is awesome haha. Never had such a quick reply

Comment: Quick reply depends on the problem ;) Feel free to mark your question as answered